# Como leerlos datos del request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, array

Necesito extraer lo que esta en request->itemes

```
Request {#40 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#472 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#480 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#42 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#48 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "{"itemes":" => array:1 [▼
        "{"Id":"1","Descripcion":"Correa","Precio":12.95,"Envolver":false},{"Id":"3","Descripcion":"T-Shirt","Precio":5.95,"Envolver":false},{"Id":"4","Descripcion":"Camisa","Precio":65.89,"Envolver":false}" => ""
      ]
    ]
  }
  +query: ParameterBag {#48 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#44 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#45 ▶}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#43 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#46 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/json"
  #requestUri: "/json?{%22itemes%22:[{%22Id%22:%221%22,%22Descripcion%22:%22Correa%22,%22Precio%22:12.95,%22Envolver%22:false},{%22Id%22:%223%22,%22Descripcion%22:%22T-Shirt%22,%22Precio%22:5.95,%22Envolver%22:false},{%22Id%22:%224%22,%22Descripcion%22:%22Camisa%22,%22Precio%22:65.89,%22Envolver%22:false}],%22total%22:%2284.79%22}"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#455 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
}
```

Comment: Podrías probar con `$datos = $request->all();` para obtener todos los datos en un array. Tu pregunta es un poco general así que no hay cómo recomendarte métodos más específicos como `$request->input` o `$request-query`

Comment: si correcto, como hago para obtener el valor de la Descripción?, que me retorne Correa, T-Shirt, Camisa.

Comment: Podrías añadir a tu pregunta la salida de `var_dump($datos)`?

Comment: Gracias, use         dd( $data->itemes[1]['Descripcion']) para acceder al valor y un bucle

Answer (score 2):

Puedes acceder a los datos con simple foreach

```
foreach ($request->itemes as $item) {
        echo $item->id;
        echo $item->descripcion;
        echo $item->precio;
        echo $item->envolver;
    }
```

El echo es para que los veas, ya con eso los puedes manipular según lo que necesites.